Pgfplots: set plot node style
When using pgfplots, is there a way to set the style for every node on a plot for a particular axis? I'm currently setting the style for each plot, but I've been unable to do the same for each node along a plot. Below is a MWE where the node should be black,but it is the same color as the plot.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.95pt, color=blue, samples=255},
      every axis plot node/.style={color=black},
      ]
      \addplot[<->] expression[domain=0:4]{x^2} node[pos=0.5, below] {$x^2$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Does  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text=black}] solve your problem?

You need to say nodes={text=black}:

at \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text=black}] or
\begin{axis}[ ... nodes={text=black}, ...]

BTW:

I do not find a key every axis plot node/.style={...} (?)
I think you do not need append style at every axis plot/.append style={...}, but whatever.



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
nodes={text=black}, 
      every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.95pt, color=blue, samples=255,},
%      every axis plot node/.style={color=black},
      ]
      \addplot[<->] expression[domain=0:4]{x^2} node[pos=0.5, below] {$x^2$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



@cls with text=black in èvery axis plot` this works too.

Sure, but I thought you want to have that 'very globally'.

That works and is way simpler than I was making it out to be. The every axis plot isn't relevant in this example other than I thought that setting the style for nodes would be like that, which is where my guess of every axis plot node came from.
